# Node js debugging in VS Code ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a node app running behind nginx on EC2.

This is my configuration in launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Remote",
            "address": "xx.214.xxx.106",
            "port":9229,
            "remoteRoot": "home/username/web/myappfolder",
            "timeout": 40000,

        },
```

I get this message:
[image]

I checked all the firewall on local and remote machines, but no use.
I think may be I have to insert username and password, but if I try to add "env" variable in launch.json, (as given in [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)), it says its not allowed. I searched the web without success. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if you have another app that use the same port as your app does?

Comment: I have only one nodejs express app running on my Ubuntu instance and that is on port 8080.

Comment: Yes but there might be other apps running that use the same port you try to open. If you try to run the app on your public IP check if you forwarded the port corectly.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem in my case.

Comment: Its seems like simple case of authentication failure. I don't see any option for authentication in launch.json. I need public key and username password to login into my EC2 instance. I am also using sftp extension successfully but sftp.json  file has options  "username": "abcd",
    "privateKeyPath": "D:/ccc/keypairfile.pem",